# Fix First column in excel during printing

Tags: xlwt, pyexcel

hi guys i am using xlwt package to export excel file . Problem is after downloading the excel file and opening it then i try to print the excel file up to here it us fine what i need is first column should be repeat for next pages also during the printing.

[image: while printing 1 st page]

above image shows the while printing the first column is shown
[image]
above image shows the printing 2 nd page there is first column 
in excel file first column is fixed but we print it is not happening